# Pow / Mavericks / Nack / RBENV / ZSH Somethng not right

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, osx-mavericks, rack-pow

I am having a quite a bit of trouble with getting pow working correctly.

I am using

```
Mavericks 
Rbenv 
ruby 1.9.3p545, 
pow 0.4.3
node v0.10.26
npm 1.4.7
```

Basically the apps I want to serve with pow, don't serve. Chrome and Firefox just keep 'waiting for myapp.dev'

viewing powder applog - which tails the log, says all the requests are being made, and shows the output almost identical to rails s (which works) except for two lines about SSL Api Calls

rails s works fine for the apps.

the mavericks resolver says dev is there.

going to localhost shows the default pow screen as if it running.

creating a brand new rail app works and serves the default rails page.

the Pow/accesslog has a normal GET request.

the Pow/apps/myapp.log has -

```
WARNING /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `unlink': No such file or directory - /tmp/nack.6042.2652029974.sock (Errno::ENOENT)
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `close'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:40:in `block in initialize'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:82:in `call'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:82:in `select'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:82:in `block in start'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:76:in `loop'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:76:in `start'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:12:in `run'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] WARNING   from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pow/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:02 GMT+0100 (BST)] DEBUG nack worker exited
[Fri Apr 25 2014 11:21:28 GMT+0100 (BST)] DEBUG nack worker 6479 spawned
```

I can't seem to find out what the problem is.  Because I will be developing multiple rails apps all the time it would be nice to be able to have them all always running.